# MVC create a list view based on id from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display a view with a table that shows elements based on id from another table. Below is an example of the two tables that i want to relate.

```
Name_tbl
-id
-Name

Measurements_tbl
id
idName (i already have foreign key setup in SSMS)
```

So, what i want is to get a result like the following query:

```
Select * from Measurements_tbl
where idName=‘1'

result:

id | MeasureDate | idName | Measure1 | Measure2
1    12/15/2018      1      10      15  
2    12/20/2018      1      25      30
3    12/25/2018      1      20      18
```

This is the setup that i have right now:

ViewModel

```
    public class DetalleNombreMedidasViewModel
    {
        public Name_tbl Names { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Measurements_tbl> Measures { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {


            var name = _context.Name_tbl.Include(p=> p.Measures_tbl).FirstOrDefault(p=>p.id==id);
            var measures = patient.Measures_tbl;


            var viewModel = new DetalleNombreMedidasViewModel
            {
                Names = name,
                Measures = measures
            };


            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

View

```
@model FahWebApp.ViewModels.DetalleNombreMedidasViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Detalles";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

this is the view that I am trying to get:

```
@foreach(var name in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td> @name.Measure1 </td>
            <td> @name.Measure2 </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

DbModel

```
namespace FahWebApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class DbModel : DbContext
    {
        public DbModel()
            : base("name=DbModel")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Direccion_tbl> Direccion_tbl { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Estado_cat> Estado_cat { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Medidas_tbl> Medidas_tbl { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Nombre_tbl> Nombre_tbl { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Pais_cat> Pais_cat { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<database_firewall_rules> database_firewall_rules { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Email)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Calle)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Colonia)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Ciudad)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.CodigoPostal)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.TelefonoCasa)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Direccion_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.TelefonoCelular)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Estado_cat>()
                .Property(e => e.Estado)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Estado_cat>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Direccion_tbl)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Estado_cat)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.idEstado)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Pecho)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Bicep)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Antebrazo)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Muñeca)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Cintura)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Cadera)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Muslo)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Medidas_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Pantorrilla)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Nombre)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Apellido)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Sexo)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_tbl>()
                .Property(e => e.Altura)
                .HasPrecision(3, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_tbl>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Direccion_tbl)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Nombre_tbl)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.idNombre)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Nombre_tbl>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Medidas_tbl)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Nombre_tbl)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.idNombre)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Pais_cat>()
                .Property(e => e.Pais)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Pais_cat>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Direccion_tbl)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Pais_cat)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.idPais)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<database_firewall_rules>()
                .Property(e => e.start_ip_address)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<database_firewall_rules>()
                .Property(e => e.end_ip_address)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your where condition checks for `idName` column instead of `id` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry., you are right, that’s what I meant.

Comment: So what is the problem then ?

Comment: That in View, @name.Measure1, 2 etc. Does not work...

Comment: you are passing a single object tot he view. why are you trying to run a foreach loop in the view ? Use a foreach loop when dealing with a collection

Comment: @Shyju sorry, I am just getting the hang of MVC... how should I modify the code to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Post the structure of your entity classes to the question.

Comment: I think the answer might lie here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application.

Comment: Just query the Measurements_tbl table with your Where condition and pass the result of that (collection to view). Change the model type of your view to `IEnumerable< Measurements_tbl>` and see what happens.